# Centering a checkbox in a GridViewColumn?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, styles

I'm currently struggling on getting my `CheckBox`es to properly center within my `GridViewColumn`s.

I've defined a `Style` for my `CheckBox`es like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="DataGridCheckBox">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}},Path=ActualWidth}" />
</Style>
```

And my `CheckBox`es are added into the `GridViewColumn` using a `DataTemplate` like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Comment">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding PropertyItem.Comment, Converter={StaticResource booleanConverter}, ConverterParameter='string'}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

But the problem I have is that the `CheckBox`es remain left-aligned (even when resizing the column).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Sonny

**EDIT:**  I've been messing around with a `CheckBox`in a blank window and I think the problem may be related to the `CheckBox`control.  If I make a very wide `CheckBox`, I still can't seem to get the `CheckBox`portion of it to align within itself.  It always wants to go to the upper-left.  As per the name, the `ContentAlignment` properties only seem to align the content.

Comment: What happens if you move the HorizontalAlignment="Center" property inline of the CheckBox and do not use a Style, same issue?

Comment: Yeah.  Same issue.  None of the alignment properties seem to make a difference, but I know the template is being applied because the checkbox is properly enabled and the properties look correct at design-time.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to apply the style to just the checkbox column? I would love to know how.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to set HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch for the ListViewItem's

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!-- ... -->
</ListView>
```

**Update**

Here's a Xaml only example which centers the CheckBoxes. Paste it and try it :)

```
<Grid>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="DataGridCheckBox">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}},Path=ActualWidth}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Comment">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBox}" IsChecked="True"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListViewItem>Item1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item2</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item3</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry, Mel.  I'm using a DataGrid and not a ListView.  Would you have some code that translates?  I can't seem to find a HorizontalContentAlignment property for my GridViewColumns.

Comment: @Sonny Boy: Which DataGrid are you using? For the MS DataGrid they are called DataGridColumn etc. so that's why I assumed you were using ListView

Comment: Sorry... I was getting confused for a second. I've made the change you suggested and see no difference.

Comment: @Sonny Boy: Made a xaml only example where the CheckBoxes are centered

Comment: Good stuff.  I've added the style into my App.xaml file and it's working across the board.  Now I just need to limit it to the columns that have CheckBoxes....  :)

Comment: It works fine but it destroys Expression Dark theme... :(  Could you tell please how to implement it and without that issue?