# Problems with ListView.ItemContainerStyle not applying

Tags: wpf, xml, listview, checkbox, alignment

**INTRODUCTION:**

My code is very similar to that discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514055/wpf-centering-a-checkbox-in-a-gridviewcolumn). I have a `CheckBox` column in a `ListView` (which is using a `GridView` as it's `View`) and I am trying to align the `CheckBox` to center inside the column.

The answer suggests adding an `ItemContainerStyle` that sets the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Center`. I've tried this and it is not applying the style.

---

**CODE:**

Here is my code so far:

```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="NoRedemptions">
          <Border BorderBrush="#FF7F9DB9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
               <TextBlock Text="No Redemptions have been added" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
          </Border>    
   </ControlTemplate>

   <Style x:Key="CellAlignmentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   </Style> 

   <Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="ListViewTriggersStyle">
         <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FundRedemptions.Count, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                  <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
                  <Setter Property="View" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
                  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NoRedemptions}"/>
              </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```

- The first item, the `ControlTemplate` called *NoRedemptions* is used when the `ListView` is empty. It essentially removes the columns of the `GridView` and just leaves a `TextBox` with a border telling the user that the `ListView` is empty.
- The second item, the `Style` called *CellAlignmentStyle* is the style as copied from the link above. This is supposed to center the `CheckBox` column.
- The last item, the `Style` called *ListViewTriggerStyle* is a style applied to the `ListView` that basically removes the bindings to it (the `ItemsSource` and the `View`) and sets the `ListView`'s `Template` to the *NoRedemptions*'s `ControlTemplate` (first bullet point), displaying the message that the `ListView` is empty when the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` (*FundRedemptions*) is empty.

Here is the `GridView` that is bound as the `ListView`'s `View` (for simplicity's sake I have omitted the irrelevant columns):

```
<GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" x:Key="ListViewView">
     <GridViewColumn x:Name="checkedColumn"  Header="Checked" Width="Auto">
           <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>                
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
```

And here is the offending ListView itself:

```
 <ListView 
             Grid.Row="3"  
             Style="{StaticResource ListViewTriggersStyle}" 
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CellAlignmentStyle}" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
             View="{StaticResource ListViewView}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FundRedemptions, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
 </ListView>
```

---

**ATTEMPTS AT SOLVING THE ISSUE**

Now as mentioned above, the `Style` described in bullet point 2, the one 'borrowed' from the above link, does not work on my `ListView`.

- I've tried using `HorizontalAlignment` instead of `HorizontalContentAlignment` and that **did not** work.
- I've tried adding other setters to the style to see if it is being applied and those setters **did** work
- I've tried changing `VerticalAlignment` to see if its an alignment issue and that **did** work.
- I've tried changing from `Stretch` as the SO post suggests to `Center` or `Right` and that **did not** work.
- I've tried making changes to the alignments of the `CheckBox` itself and that **did not** work
- I've tried adding the alignment to the GridView or to the `ListView`'s style itself and this **did not** work.
- I've tried pasting an exact copy of the `ListView` in the SO post's answer and that copy **did** works
- I've tried removing the bindings of the `Style` and `ItemsSource`, and then just adding `<ListViewItem>Item1</ListViewItem>` in the body of the `ListView` (in order to see if it had to do with the `ItemsSource` or `Style` and this **did not** work.
- I've tried styling the `CheckBox` to match the exact style set in the example and that **did not** work.

---

**IN CONCLUSION**

What baffles me the most is that there really isn't very different at all from the example in the post but for some reason it isn't working. I can't think of anything else to try.

u_u

---

**EDIT**

Ok so I have finished reconstructing my grid from the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514055/wpf-centering-a-checkbox-in-a-gridviewcolumn) by incrementally adding more of my styles and triggers to the `GridView`.

*I have found nothing.*

I'm so frustrated, what could it possibly be? The order of the `Style`s and `Template`s in the `UserControl.Resources` is changed, could that have made a difference without causing an outright error?

At this point I'm too scared of breaking it to play around with the styles and figure it out.

u_u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question will remain a mystery, because I basically deleted the code and reconstructed it and it worked. I can't reproduce the error.

For those of you looking at this question in the future, I did stumble upon a simple and painfully obvious fix to this issue. Provided the column is going to be a set width (which I imagine will be most of the cases, seeing as CheckBoxes are mostly the same size) you can just set a margin for the `CheckBox` to bump the `CheckBox` to the middle of the column. Simple. Why I didn't think about it is beyond me but I really wanted to understand what I did wrong. Oh well...

u_u

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce this, maybe you have one or more styles in the `Application.Resources` (e.g. a full theme) which interferes, those styles apply within `ControlTemplates` and potentially screw things up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked around the program but could find nothing that relates to a `ListView` or `GridView` or anything that would make any kind of sense. Plus I actually copied Meleak 's code exactly and posted it in the same control right next to mine, and his code worked.

I think what I'm going to do is take his code and slowly reconstruct my listview from it piece by piece, should see where the error comes in. I'll post what I find.